# round corners of only one side of a uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

[image: Rounded corner]

I know how to round the all four corners by setting the corner radius similar to this:

```
 func rounded() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
    }
```

but am unsure how to round only 2 corners. Any help is appreciated.

[image]I'm trying to round the corners of only one side of a UIView like this:

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
extension UIView {
    func roundedLeftTopBottom(){
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        let maskPath1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds,
                                     byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .bottomLeft],
                                     cornerRadii: CGSize(width:self.frame.size.height / 2, height:self.frame.size.height / 2))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPath1.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer1
    }

    // or

    func round () {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner]
    }
}
```

Make sure to call any of those ones inside `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` if the view is inside a vc so to have the right frame size

Comment: func round worky only on iOS11+

Comment: yes , it does the op is free to use anyone according to it's case

Comment: I tried using the UIView extension but it looks like there is blank space where the rounding is supposed to happen.

Comment: @Sh_Khan I just added a screen shot of what I'm talking about

Comment: can you set `view.clipsToBounds = true`